Pattern in Sequential Drawing Probability
While studying probability, I noticed a pattern in calculating probabilities for problems involving drawing specific objects in sequence (without replacement). The probability can be expressed as:
P(success) = P(n,r)/P(N,r)
Where:
n = number of desired objects
N = total objects
r = number of consecutive draws needed
Example Problem
Consider drawing 3 red balls in a row from an urn:
3 red balls
2 blue balls
n = 3 (red balls)
N = 5 (total balls)
r = 3 (consecutive draws needed)
P(success) = P(3,3)/P(5,3)
= [3!/(3-3)!] / [5!/(5-3)!]
= 6/60
= 1/10
This matches the traditional solution method:
(3/5) × (2/4) × (1/3) = 1/10
Are there theorems that explain this pattern?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Instead of looking for isolated theorems, I suggest that you try to find the right probability textbook for you.

For your particular problem, the two "usual" ways are

the multiplcative way, $\Large{\frac35 \cdot \frac24 \cdot \frac13}$

using combinations, $\large{\dfrac{\binom33}{\binom53}}$

What you are proposing is to use permutations instead of combinations. Since both numerator and denominator of the Combinations approach wiil be multiplied by $3!$, you will get the same answer, but what is the advantage you gain ? Moreover, since we are drawing only red balls here, why permute ?


